# Bitcoin segwit addresses from HEX

Tags: segregated-witness, address-generation

I loved those two

- https://github.com/grondilu/bitcoin-bash-tools
- https://www.bitaddress.org/

because you can convert HEX into WIF private key.

Is there something similar what allows to create Segwit Bitcoin addresses from HEX? It is useful for those who want to dice wallet.

Comment: How are you creating it, can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

Best similar and alternative is Bitwasp for PHP, with a few lines you can create much more than addresses and keys.

### Presently supported:

- Bloom filters
- Blocks, headers, and Merkle blocks
- P2SH & Segregated witness scripts
- An adaptable elliptic-curve library, using [[PhpEcc](https://github.com/mdanter/phpecc)] by default, or libsecp256k1 if the bindings are found
- Support for building, parsing, signing/validating transactions
- Deterministic signatures (RFC6979)
- BIP32 and electrum (older type I) deterministic key algorithms
- ScriptFactory for common input/output types, parser, interpreter, and classifiers
- Supports bindings to libbitcoinconsensus
- RPC bindings to Bitcoin Core's RPC
- Bindings to Stratum (electrum) servers
- Easy serialization to binary representation of most classes
- SIGHASH types when creating transactions
- Payment Protocol (BIP70)

Take a look [bitcoin-php](https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-php)